# Vim Plug installment error on MacOS: Error creating directory /Users/api/.vim/autoload

Tags: vimrc, terminal, macvim, macos, plugin-vim-plug

I just migrated today from VSCode to Vim, and I need a little bit of help regarding the installation of Vim Plug.
I installed Vim with Homebrew, and now I want to install Vim Airline. The tutorial I am following uses Vim Plug for this.
This is the code block to install Vim Plug, according to the tutorial:

```
    $ curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
```

When I insert it to the Terminal, it gives the following error:

```
    Error creating directory /Users/api/.vim/autoload.
```

I browsed the documentation, but I did not find a solution. I am using Big Sur 11.6, if it helps.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Do you already have a `~/.vim` and `~/.vim/autoload` directory? The command doesn't create directories for you; try it with the `--create-directories` option to `curl`.

Comment: If you have (some of) the directories, make sure the permissions are correct. For example, you can use `ls -ld ~/.vim` and check whether it's owned by your user or by root. (If you use a `sudo` command to initially created, it might end up being owned by root, in which case you won't be able to create subdirectories...)